# Trouble building rosserial_windows library from source

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am I'm pretty new to ROS and trying to build the rosserial_windows library to create a ros publisher node in my c++ project.
I am attempting to follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World), but I can't use the instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosserial-windows
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosserial-server
```

because I'm using **ros-for-windows**
I tried the instruction from [ms-iot consuming a ROS package](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/UsingROSonWindows.html)

```
choco install ros-melodic-rosserial-windows
```

but that package doesn't exist. Trying the next step:

```
rosinstall_generator rosserial_windows --deps --exclude RPP --tar --flat > pkg.rosinstall
rosinstall_generator rosserial_server --deps --exclude RPP --tar --flat > pkg.rosinstall

wstool init src
wstool merge -r -y -t src pkg.rosinstall
wstool update -t src

rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y

catkin_make
```

The catkin_make threw an error

```
C:\opt\~\src\rosserial_server\include\rosserial_server/topic_handlers.h(40): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rosserial_msgs/RequestMessageInfo.h': No such file or directory
```

In the "ros\melodic\x64\include\rosserial_msgs" there is no "RequestMessageInfo.h"
Okay different tact, new workspace, I cloned the rosserial repository.

```
git clone -b melodic-devel  https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
catkin_make
catkin_make install
```

works fine.
*side note:* I compared the cloned "rosserial_server/topic_handlers.h" with the rosinstall_generator "rosserial_server/topic_handlers.h" and the cloned one didn't include RequestMessageInfo.h
back to the original tutorial:

```
devel\setup.bat
rosrun rosserial_windows make_libraries.py my_library
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named make_libraries.py
```

This seems to be an issue with "rosserial_windows"'s CMakeList.txt not pointing to the correct "make_libraries.py" path but as far as I can tell, which isn't very far, it is pointing to it

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rosserial_windows)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
  rosserial_client
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS)

install(
  DIRECTORY src/ros_lib
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/src
)

catkin_install_python(
  PROGRAMS src/${PROJECT_NAME}/make_libraries.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

- the path to the "rosserial_windows" package is:

  \src\rosserial\rosserial_windows

-the path to "make_libraries.py" is:

```
<catkin workspace>\src\rosserial\rosserial_windows\src\rosserial_windows\make_libraries.py
```

I'm very confused, I've just spent the last 7 hours trying to build a library ;~;
What's the blatantly obvious thing I've missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354397/trouble-building-rosserial_windows-library-from-source/) by [David_milne](https://answers.ros.org/users/55076/david_milne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a workaround by using the path from the package root folder to the "make_libraries.py"

```
rosrun rosserial_windows src\rosserial_windows\make_libraries.py my_library
```

The library has been build which was my original problem. I'm guessing that the package is looking in its root folder and not the folder pointed to in **CMakeList.txt**
The problem is that I don't know why and I realised this because a different package had the exact same error, but that is a different question. I did a search for "ros-for-windows not finding python files" and I found [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/326072/windows10-rosrun-couldnt-find-python-scripts-in-path-scripts/) which gave me the workaround.

---

Originally posted by [David_milne](https://answers.ros.org/users/55076/david_milne/) with karma: 16 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0